# Varnish # Symbol not found

Tags: caching, varnish, vcl

Hi Im trying to setup my varnish server

When I try to running Varnish with this command for debugging I

```
 varnishd -d -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl
```

Get this the error :

```
Symbol not found: 'ipcast.clientip' (expected type BOOL):
('input' Line 101 Pos 9)
    if (ipcast.clientip(req.http.X-Forwarded-For) != 0) {

--------###############-----------------------------------
```

Now im not sure how I should read this error message, Could it be my backend servers are not defined correctly? or should be looking somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message means that the ipcast VMOD isn't properly loaded.

Add `import ipcast;` to the VCL.